# Is there any way to drag from grid table viewer and drop it to nat table

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I've added DragListener in GridTable viewer and DropListener in nat table but when I select any row grid viewer and drop it nat table ; selected data is not getting dropped
Code snippet is attached below

Drag Source listener in GridTableViewer

```
Transfer[] transferTypes = new Transfer[] { LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer() };

this.gridTableViewer.addDragSupport(DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE, transferTypes, new DragSourceListener() {

      @Override
      public void dragStart(final DragSourceEvent event) {
        System.out.println(transferTypes);
        event.doit = !ShowListDialog.this.gridTableViewer.getStructuredSelection().isEmpty();
    }

      @Override
      public void dragSetData(final DragSourceEvent event) {
        if(LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().isSupportedType(event.dataType)) {
           LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer()
 .setSelection(ShowListDialog.this.gridTableViewer.getStructuredSelection());
           LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().setSelectionSetTime(event.time & 0xFFFF);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void dragFinished(final DragSourceEvent dragsourceevent) {
        // LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().setSelection(null);
        // LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().setSelectionSetTime(0);
      }
    });
```

DropTargetListener in NatTable

```
Transfer[] transferTypes = new Transfer[] { LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer() };

this.natTable.addDropSupport(DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE, transferTypes, new DropTargetListener() {

      @Override
      public void dragEnter(final DropTargetEvent event) {
        event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE;
        event.currentDataType = event.dataTypes[0];
      }

      @Override
      public void dragOperationChanged(final DropTargetEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      @Override
      public void dragOver(final DropTargetEvent event) {
        event.detail = DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE;
      }

      @Override
      public void drop(final DropTargetEvent event) {
        StructuredSelection structuredSelection = (StructuredSelection) event.data;
        final Object selectedElement = structuredSelection.getFirstElement();
        // for (Object selectedElement : structuredSelection.toList()) {
        if (selectedElement instanceof String) {

        }
      }

      @Override
      public void dropAccept(final DropTargetEvent event) {

      }

      @Override
      public void dragLeave(final DropTargetEvent droptargetevent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of `LocalSelectionTransfer` explains that somehow:

> The selection is made available directly for use in the DropTargetListener.
>   dropAccept method. The DropTargetEvent passed to dropAccept does not contain
>   the drop data.

So instead of trying to retrieve the selection from the `DropTargetEvent` you need to access the `LocalSelectionTransfer` directly like this:

```
LocalSelectionTransfer transfer = LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer();
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) transfer.getSelection();
```

Comment: Thank you,but even on retrieving selection from Local selection transfer it didn't work

Comment: On dragging any item from grid table viewer only dragStart() method is invoked other than that no other methods from either of the listeners  DragListener and DropListener is being invoked.

Comment: The grid table viewer from where drag is initiated is created on right click of row in nat table.The same listeners for drag and drop works when I drag any item from Tree Viewer which is not inside nat table

Comment: I don't get it why this happens?

Comment: Maybe DND.DROP_MOVE is an issue.

Comment: Actually the grid table viewer is created inside dialog which blocks the operation in other widget like nat table.This works on adding setBlockOnOpen(false) in setStyle() of dialog